# Creating subtags for tags and automatically showing up in favourites

Tags: feature-request, tags

I'll explain my feature request with an example.

If you have [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) in your favourite tags in SO, then automatically [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) tagged posts should show up shaded on your front page. Because any C++11 question is obviously also a C++ question.

I think there should be a feature to mark a tag as a child tag or sub tag of a parent tag.

Another thing is that a [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) may be interesting today but 3-4 years down the line when most C++ compilers are C++11 complaint, then a tag like C++11 may be irrelevant - so searching under the [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) should also search implicitly amongst question tagged only as [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)

Comment: While I like the general idea of this feature I would like to point out that there are certain cases where a subtag (like c++11 in this instance) would not actually imply the super-tag. For instance a question might be specific to why c++11 decided to change the standard in some way. This would not necessarily relate to the c++ tag, but would relate to c++11.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple solutions. Tag favorites support wildcards, so `c++*` would match both `c++` and `c++11`. You can also add both to your favorites, which is an easy solution.

The tag synonym system already accomplishes your second request - for tags which are truly identical, both will, in effect, be marked.

Comment: 1. C++11 is a very specific case where a wild card on the original tag may match the subtag. What if C++11 were instead called [tag:timbaktoo]. 2. The wild card solution will not work. 2. C++11 is not a synonym for C++. It's a subset or a superset depending on how you look at it.

Comment: @user93353 Yes, you're right, on both counts. In the first case, just add another tag preference. For the second, you can't assume everyone who wants the C++ tag also wants the C++11 tag - that defeats the purpose of the favorite tag system.